# ERROR TypeError: .forEach is not a function

Tags: angular

In my Angular program, I need to create a deep copy of my object so that I'll be able to compare the changes. Here is what I tried and I get an error in my console that says `ERROR TypeError: .forEach is not a function`. How do I fix this?

```html
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import { PTOData } from './pto-data';
import { PTODataService } from './pto-data.service';
import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info';
import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';

@Component({
    selector: '[pto-row-edit]',
    templateUrl: `./row-edit.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./row-edit.component.css']
})

export class RowEditComponent implements OnInit {

    // Inputs & Outputs to/from grid component
    @Input() pto: PTOData[];
    @Input() rowSelected: number;

    @Output() onDelete = new EventEmitter<number>();
    @Output() onSave = new EventEmitter<number>();

    opto: PTOData[];

    private initialized: boolean = false;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.opto = [];
        this.pto.forEach(x => this.opto.push(x))
        console.log(this.opto);
    }

    constructor(
        private ptodataService: PTODataService,
        private empInfoService: EmpInfoService) { }

    resetRow(pto: PTOData): void {
        console.log(this.pto);
        console.log(this.opto);
        this.rowSelected = null;
        this.onSave.emit(this.rowSelected);
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like it should work. Is it possible that the input to this component doesn't actually send an array?

Comment: @SaxyPandaBear well I guess that fixes the problem. whenever I do a basic `console.log(this.pto)` it displays it and says that it's an object. How would I replicate something like this but for an object?

Comment: If you look using developer tools on something like Chrome or Firefox, can you see what the contents of the object are? Does it contain an array in it?

Comment: @SaxyPandaBear yeah, it displays `Object {ID: 180424, EmpKey: 1, type: "PTO", ...}` where the `...` is the rest of my requested fields

Comment: It looks like whatever component is giving your RowEditComponent it's input is only giving it a single object. Make sure that the input is actually of type PTOData[], not just PTOData. You can try to circumvent this by going into the other component and do something like `let foo: PTOData[] = []; foo.push(myInput);` and then pass in `foo` instead.

Comment: If you want to clone an object instead of an array, use `this.opto = Object.assign({}, originalObject);` or (my preferred method, since it has better TypeScript type-checking support) the _spread_ operator: `this.opto =
 {...originalObject};`.

Comment: @Mike that works perfectly. thanks so much! if you want to put that as an answer, i'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments on the original question. The original issue, as @SaxyPandaBear pointed out, was that an array value was expected for the `@Input() pto` field rather than a plain object, so the declared type needed to be changed and the array-cloning statement needed to be replaced with an object-cloning statement.

---

If you want to clone an object instead of an array, use:

```
this.opto = Object.assign({}, originalObject);
```

or (my preferred method, since it has better TypeScript type-checking support) the *spread* operator:

```
this.opto = {...originalObject};
```